# Parsing XML in Go after accessing it through io/ioutil net/http

Tags: xml, http, go

Any idea why this parsing is not working when accessing the XML directly from the site and it works when I copy and paste it into a var?

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/xml"
  "fmt"
  "strings"
  "io/ioutil"
  "net/http"
)

type Sitemapindex struct {
  Locations []Location `xml:"channel>item"`
}

type Location struct {
  Loc string `xml:"title"`
}

func (e Location) String () string {
  return fmt.Sprintf(e.Loc)
}

func main() {
  resp, _ := http.Get("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/xbrlrss.all.xml")
  bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)  
  string_body := string(bytes)  
  var s Sitemapindex
  decoder := xml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(string_body))
  decoder.Strict = false
  decoder.Decode(&s)
  fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Comment: You are ignoring the error yielded by decoder.Decode, it's you very first mistake.

Answer (score 4):

The content you're parsing is encoded as `windows-1252`. To properly decode this data, the XML decoder needs to be parameterized by a charset reader that can read the specified charset.

```
import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "golang.org/x/net/html/charset"
)

decoder := xml.NewDecoder(reader)
decoder.CharsetReader = charset.NewReaderLabel
err := decoder.Decode(&s)
```

I guess that the `error` returned at your attempt to decode the data tells something similar.

Comment: Thanks for this ... now I am getting undefined: charset.NewReaderLabel     any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're probably missing the import to `"golang.org/x/net/html/charset"`

Comment: I added it to the import...since this import does not come standard with golang, how would you recommend adding it?

Comment: You can use `go get -u golang.org/x/net/html/charset` from the command line.